# C# managed EWS - search in GAL

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to search for several people in the GAL (global adress list) on a exchange server through `Managed EWS`.

Currently, Iam using the `ResolveName()`-function. For single searches, its perfect. But now I want to use more than one queries at once.

```
    public IEnumerable<Person> searchInGAL(string query)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) || query.ToLower().Equals("smtp:"))
            yield break;

        PropertySet AllProps = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        NameResolutionCollection ncCol = _service.ResolveName(query, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, AllProps);
        foreach (NameResolution nr in ncCol)
        {
            yield return new Person { Name = nr.Contact.DisplayName, Email = nr.Contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Address, Alias = nr.Contact.Alias };
        }
     }
```

Is there a limiter to break a query into parts? I tested "", "`,`" and "`;`" already. Not working.

Edit: "`,`" (with a white-space) and "`|`" also dosen't work.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are using the GAL? As the GAL is based on ActiveDirectory you might found it easier to check a DomainController via LDAP (there are libraries for that). Additional to that the LDAP connection will work regardless if the Exchange server got an upgrade (e.g. 2010 to 2016) which might have API changes.

Comment: I havn't access to the DC (not the same network). The software has only remote access to the exchange-service.